# Transparency of terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

How to make terminal transparent in UBUNTU 14.04. Actually I want to make my ubuntu terminal transparent but the solution given for the same question is not applicable because the given thing that to go to edit->profile preferences-> Background tab. But the problem is there is no background tab there. So what to do?

Comment: Post screen-shot of Edit>profile preferences.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is under the "colors" tab. Mid-way down is a checkbox and a slide bar adjust it. Slide it all the way to the right to get full transparency. Below is a picture of it.

[image]